# COM Object Clean Up

Tags: c#, c++, com, activex, components

What is the difference between the two lines of code below:

```
CComPtr< IInterface > m_interface;

IInterface* m_interface;
```

I know that CComPtr help eliminate memory leaks, but I am getting inconsistent results. When declaring the pointer with `CComPtr< IInterface > m_interface;`
and using the interface in my C# code there are no errors, however using the Interface in VC++  I get an unhandled exception error, even if I comment out the instance creation of IInterface.

I am pretty sure the problem is in here somewhere:

```
STDMETHODIMP CSomeClass::get_IClass(IClass** var)
{ 
      return m_class_var->QueryInterface(var);
}
STDMETHODIMP CSomeClass::putref_IClass(IClass* var)
{ 
     m_class_var = var;
     return S_OK;
}
```

When I declare the interface pointer with: `IInterface* m_interface;` 
I get a RPC_E_SERVERFAULT error when testing the Interface in C# and have to explicitly call GC.Collect() to avoid the error being thrown after instantiation of a few objects. When testing the Interface in VC++ the error is consistent however when it occurs is different. If I comment out the instance creation of IInterface the code runs fine, however when I try to create an instance I get same error as before, just a vague unhandled exception error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You really should spend 15 minutes crafting a very short snippet that would demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You say "using the Interface in VC++ I get an unhandled exception error" - can you show us the code using the interface in VC++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IInstance* m_instance` is a simple pointer to an IInstance object.  You have to manage the lifetime of this pointer yourself.  You don't `new` and `delete` COM objects like you would ordinary objects.  Instead, the operating system allocates the object when you call the WINAPI function `CoCreateInstance' :

```
// instantiate the CoClass which implements IInstance...
IInstance* instance = 0;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(mylibrary::MyCoClass), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(mylib::IInstance), &instance);

:   :

// We're done, so release the object...
instance->Release();
instance = 0;
```

Each COM object implements reference counting.  When the last reference to an object has been `Release()`ed, the COM object destroys itself.

Using `CComPtr<>` simplifies how you manage the lifetime of the COM objects.  It is a smart pointer similar in nature to std::auto_ptr or Boost's shared_ptr, but it works with COM objects.  Typically when using a CComPtr you would call the `CreateInstance` member function rather than calling the WINAPI function, and you would not explicitly call `Release` when you are done.  Just let the CComPtr go out of scope, and when it's destructor is called it will call `Release` for you:

```
void function()
{
  // instantiate the CoClass which implements IMyInterface...
  CComPtr<IInstance> instance;
  instance.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(mylibrary::MyCoClass));

  :   :

  // We're done, so release the object...
  // dont have to do anything, it will be released when function() exits
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`CComPtr` is a smart pointer designed to do the 'right' thing when used with COM idioms.

Your code for `get_IClass` looks good, but `putref_IClass` needs to call `AddRef` on the `IClass` as you're storing it. If you used `CComPtr` that would happen automatically.

You'll need to add more details about your VC++ unhandled exception.

Comment: Thank you. this help understand a bit better. I would vote you up but I don't have enough reputation points

Answer (score 0):

CComPtr< IInterface > m_interface is an object. Whereas IInterface* m_interface is a pointer.

The first will have its destructor called when it goes out of scope and I think (a long time since I used it) it will automatically call m_interface ->Release().

The latter is a pointer to an interface and you have to manage when m_interface->Release() is called.

Can you confirm that the COM object is not being released before access?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question a bit to give more information. I am calling Release() within the VC++ code testing Interface implementation.  Its not helping, I suspect I need release/destroy the Object within the unmanaged code even when using CComPtr< IInterface > but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Reggie: Sometimes you do need to call AddRef/Release on an object, even if it's managed by a CComPtr. You'll need to show us the VC++ code so we can see if you're doing something wrong.